# Select rows that satisfy a condition calculated in an stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a stored procedure which takes a parameter and returns true or false.

I need to select from a table those rows that stored procedure returns true for them.

For example, suppose my table has the columns: `IdEmployee`, `Name`, `Address` and `Phone`

The stored procedure takes an `IdEmployee` and returns `true` or `false` if the employee has contracted a service or not respectively.

Finally, once I get the set of rows filtered, those that have a service contracted, I need to filter them again to obtain those rows that satisfy some other conditions to finally get the final result.

The best would be to obtain the final result using a single select and from that select, execute the stored procedure for each row in where clause to select those that stored procedure returns true. Unfortunately, it is not possible, I cannot execute a store procedure from within a `select` (where clause).

I cannot change the stored procedure to a function, and I do not want to use a cursor.

I was thinking in create a scalar function that calls the stored procedure and then use the scalar function within the select.

How can I do this? Any ideas?

Comment: You have little choice but to use a loop, probably with a cursor.

Comment: Can you add the procedure code and your query to your question?  This is probably possible using a different approach, but you have not provided enough information for us to explore what they might be.

Comment: Can you rewrite the current function to output all the ID's for the service contracted. You could then save them to a table and just use a join.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried [INSERT-EXEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql#OtherTables) myself but it may be what you need. If you create a temp table or table variable and populate with INSERT-EXEC then you can use that table to filter.

```
--INSERT...EXECUTE procedure example  
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeSales   
EXECUTE dbo.uspGetEmployeeSales;  
GO
```